# Aframe with NextJs on typescript (can't use tags)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, model, next.js, aframe

I am new to aframe and cannot get my way around it. I was able to load the Aframe but cannot use the tags I want to use tags like  and more over that, I cannot load a model with an Entity, let alone making it animate. I must be doing something wrong.

I have used react-three fiber's useLoader to load previously and used the useAnimation hook to load the animation before. I just want to simply load the model and make it animate.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Scene, Entity } from "aframe-react";

export default function right() {
  const [fr, setFr] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    require("aframe");
    console.log(require("aframe-react"));
    setFr(true);
    document
      .querySelector("a-assets")
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.scene}>
        {fr && (
          <Scene background={{ color: "#004f00" }}>
            <Entity
              fbx-model="/ASSASSIN_07.fbx"
              scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"
              material={{ color: "orange" }}
              position={{ x: 0, y: 0, z: -15 }}
            />
            <Entity
              light={{ type: "directional" }}
              position={{ x: 0, y: 10, z: -5 }}
            />
            <Entity
              geometry={{ primitive: "box" }}
              material={{ color: "red" }}
              position={{ x: 0, y: 0, z: -5 }}
            />
          </Scene>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating primitives solved it for me like:

```
<Scene>
          <Entity primitive="a-assets">
            <Entity
              primitive="a-asset-item"
              id="model"
              crossOrigin="null"
              src="yourModel.fbx"
              modify-materials
            />
          </Entity>
.
.

</Scene>
```